# ajax. string from javascript to asp.cs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

problems to pass data from javascript to asp.cs with ajax.
It doesn't work. I want to pass a string with the results of a listbox.
What's the matter?
thanks

```
    public static bool AddNewItem(string name, string surname, int age)
    {


    return true;      
   } 


   <input type="submit"  value="OK" id="enter" runat="server" onclick="submitAjax()" />



      function submitAjax() {
     var listBox = document.getElementById('SubCat');
     var i;
     var str=listBox.options[0].text;

     for(i=1;i<listBox.options.length;i++)
     str=","+listBox.options[i].text;

       $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'RicercaAdvForn.aspx/AddNewItem',
        data: '{str}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg.d) {
                alert("Successfully added new item");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error! Try again...");
        }
      } );

      }
```

Comment: Please define what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: It visualize: Error! Try again...

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the parameters individually.

```
data: {name: 'someName', surname: 'someSurName', age: 20}
```

Comment: I tried also in this way bau it always return   "Error! Try again..."

Comment: Use the developer console to see what's happening in the request.

Answer (score 0):

`data: '{str}',` will pass the string literal "{str}" to your code behind - probably not what you meant. Try using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) instead:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: JSON.stringify({ parameterName: str }),
    ...
```

Where `parameterName` is the name of the parameter your code behind method is expecting.

Comment: Are you using any debugging tools such as Fiddler or the console in chrome/firefox? Are there are any errors? Does Fiddler show any outgoing request?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
data: {str},
```

Not

```
data: '{str}',
```

But is a best pranticle use the @Marcus Recck response.

Greetings.